# Python using string operation a[start:end] adds a new line character

Tags: python, python-3.x

so i have a function which I have defined like this

```
def find_between( s, first, last ):
    try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""
```

now s is taken from a file. So it has new lines. 
When I print the value of s just before try: then the output does not show \n characters

but when I print s[start:end] it starts to add the \n characters everywhere.

Now I know that this seems to be due to the string operations, but is there a way to get rid of this display of \n character?

Comment: `string.strip()` or `string.replace("\n","")`

Comment: This code will not insert new lines that were not there already. Presumably your starting string actually does have newlines in it. Or your output string actually does _not_ have newlines in it. Or there is a problem in some bit of code you have not posted.

Comment: you have a `try:` but no `except:`, are you sure this is the entire code?

Answer (score 0):

you can use string.strip() when you get the data.